# How to filter results in mongodb based on some other collection field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 schemas (let's say t1 and t2)

I need to fetch n documents from t1 with certain criteria, such that some field of t1 also exists in t2.

This works, but if t1 has millions of documents and I only need to get the first 5 matching documents, then it would be stupid to fetch all.

```
 responses = [];
    const data = await t1.find({});
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      await t2.findOne({
         t2.field : t1.field,
         t2.field2 : someOtherInfo
      }).then((obj) => responses.push(data[i]));
      if (responses.length > n) break;
    }
    return responses;
```

I have tried to use limit, but I cannot figure out the filtering part. Hence, this crude solution.
What is the better way to do this?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can try using an [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html) query. There are aggregation stages like `$match` and `$lookup`, which are of use with the query you are trying.